# Updating multi row in a table that correspond to another table with multi row

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I really don't know how to start this one so I tried to write it here. 
I have two tables: **SUBJECT** and **TAKEN-SUBJECT**

```html
SUBJECT  
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>SCODE</th>
    <th>DAY</th>
    <th>TIME</th>
    <th>SLOT</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>MATH</td>
    <td>TTH</td>
    <td>7:30-9:00</td>
    <td>19</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ENGLISH</td>
    <td>TTH</td>
    <td>9:30-11:00</td>
    <td>19</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>PE 1</td>
    <td>MWF</td>
    <td>3:00-4:00</td>
    <td>19</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>MATH</td>
    <td>MWF</td>
    <td>9:30-10:30</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
</table> 


</br>
</br>


TAKEN SUBJECT 
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>SCODE</th>
    <th>DAY</th>
    <th>TIME</th>
   
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>MATH</td>
    <td>TTH</td>
    <td>7:30-9:00</td>
   
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ENGLISH</td>
    <td>TTH</td>
    <td>9:30-11:00</td>
   
  </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>PE 1</td>
    <td>MWF</td>
    <td>3:30-4:00</td>
    
  </tr>

</table>
```

All subjects has 20 slot so every subject taken it deduct the slot to 1 and if all the taken subject will become deleted it will return the slot to the subject so it become 20 again all the 3 subject that has 19.

//QUERY TAKEN SUBJECT

```
$check=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM takensubject where S_ID = '$S_ID' and SchoolYear ='$Sy' and Semester ='$Sem'ORDER BY SubjectCode ASC ");
    $checkrows=mysqli_num_rows($check);
    if($checkrows>0) {  
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check)) {
      $scode = $row['SubjectCode'];
      $day = $row['Day'];
      $time= $row['Time'];
      $Slot = $row['Slot'];
    }
  }
```

// end

//UPDATE QUERY

```
$check="UPDATE schedule set Slot = Slot + 1 where SubjectCode='$scode' and Day='$day' and Time='$time'";
    if (mysqli_query($link, $check)) {
        echo "Update Success ";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
```

//END

But It it only update 1 subject 
How to work with it?

Comment: Put the `update` in the `while` loop, or assign the values to an array then iterate over that.

Comment: how to apply while loop in update

Comment: The `update` goes in the `while`. Move where you close `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check)) {`.

Comment: I mean how should I make it in array

Comment: `$scode[]=` etc will make them arrays you then can iterate over it and use the key to pull each field.

Comment: I've done it already like this $scode[ ] = $row['SubjectCode']; then make it update schedule  set slot = slot + 1 where SubjectCode = '$scode[ ] but it doesn't solve. I don't know how to make it in a foreach

Comment: Put them all inside `foreach( $scode as $key => $code) { ` then `$code` is your value and you can use `$key` for the other values. Alternatively you could build the full text on that index..